# How to output plist items into an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I'm trying to output the results from the following plist where checked is 1 (checked is a BOOL from the plist). The issue I'm having is that when I try to output the text into a providersArray it outputs them one after another and not in one array like "text1,text2,text3," etc...

My syntax is causing me the problem. any help would be great.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Providers" ofType:@"plist"];
dataArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in dataArray)
{
    text = [dictionary valueForKey:@"text"];
    checked = [dictionary valueForKey:@"checked"];
    NSLog(@"%@ checked value is: %@", text, checked);


    if ([checked boolValue]) {
        NSString *providers = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",text ];
        NSLog(@"providers are %@", providers);

       NSArray *providersArray = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

      NSLog(@"providersArray are %@", providersArray);


    }

}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to separate text into words separated by commas, and put those words into an array? If so, where does the next set of words (from the next dictionary in your for-in loop) go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place `NSArray *providersArray` out of loop.

To prevent it from getting initialized again and again and lose its previous value, use `addObject:` on it.